# Не получается считать объект с Firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

Создаю простой мессенджер. При попытке отобразить сообщение приложение вылетает. В логах пишет: не удалость преобразовать String(из Firebase) в ChatMessage.

```
package com.friendlychat.messages

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.friendlychat.model.*
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.xwray.groupie.GroupAdapter
import com.xwray.groupie.GroupieViewHolder
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_chat_log.*
import java.util.*

class ChatLogActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()

    var toUser: User? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_log)

        toUser = intent.getParcelableExtra(NewConversationActivity.USER_KEY)

        supportActionBar?.title = toUser?.username

        newMessages_recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        sendMessage_button.setOnClickListener {
            performSendMessage()
        }
        listenForMessages()
    }

    private fun listenForMessages() {
        val fromId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
        val toId = toUser?.uid
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/user-messages/$fromId/$toId")

        ref.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
            override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {

//            ***********************************
//                ПРОБЛЕМА ЗДЕСЬ
//            ***********************************

                val chatMessage:ChatMessage? = p0.getValue(ChatMessage::class.java)

                if (chatMessage?.fromId == FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid) {
                    if (chatMessage==null)return
                    adapter.add(ChatFromItem(chatMessage, toUser!!))
                } else {
                    if (chatMessage==null)return
                    val currentUser = NewMessagesActivity.currentUser ?: return
                    adapter.add(ChatToItem(chatMessage, currentUser))
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            }

            override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
            }

            override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            }
        })
    }

    private fun performSendMessage() {

        val user = intent.getParcelableExtra<User>(NewConversationActivity.USER_KEY)
        val toId = user.uid
        val fromId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
        val text = message_editText.text.toString()
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/user-messages/$fromId/$toId")
        val fromRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/user-messages/$toId/$fromId")
        val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()



        if (fromId == null) return

        val chatMessage = ChatMessage(id, toId, fromId, text)

        ref.setValue(chatMessage).addOnSuccessListener {
            message_editText.text.clear()
            newMessages_recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)
        }
        fromRef.setValue(chatMessage)
    }
}


package com.friendlychat.model

class ChatMessage(
    val id: String,
    val toId: String,
    val fromId: String,
    val text: String,
    val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
) {
    constructor() : this("", "", "", "", -1)
}
```

Скриншот Firebase
[image: Screenshot]

Скриншот лога:
[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое бывает, когда переменная String, но в базе данных она без " ". Вообще, Вы получаете все данные через переменную `chatMessage`, попробуйте создать одну переменную для одного значения, и если все будет работать, то добавьте еще одну и т.д., и когда будет краш, то поймете с каким значением проблема.